# Spring Rest Does DTOs can be BiDirectional?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, oop

**I am very much new to Spring REST Api. Couple of doubts:**

***DOUBT1:***

```
class UserDTO {
    long id;
    String name;
    int age;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**CASE1:**

```
public void doSomethng(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO){
    repository.findById(userDTO.getId());
}
```

**CASE2:**

```
public void doSomethng(@RequestBody long id){ //Is this correct?
    repository.findById(id);
}
```

**CASE3:**

```
public void doSomethng(@RequestBody Map<Long, Object> map){ //Is this correct?
    repository.findById(map.get("id"));
}
```

**I actually need to pass only "id" for POST Request.**

**So, Out of above 3 cases, which is a good practice? for me long id seems reasonable. I am not understanding, in which cases Passing Map as RequestBody is much better than DTO?**

***DOUBT2:***

I am currently using DTOs as BiDirectional. **So, Using Bidirectional for DTOs is correct? Will am I going to face any issues with below DTOs design?**

```
class UserDTO {
    long id;
    List<OrderDTO> orders;
}

class OrderDTO {
    long orderId;
    UserDTO userDTO;
}
```

Comment: Looking for answers still..

Answer (score 0):

> So, Out of above 3 cases, which is a good practice? for me long id seems reasonable. I am not understanding, in which cases Passing Map as RequestBody is much better than DTO?

For above case, since you just need the id field, and want to perform a search on the basis of it, my suggestion would be to use a @PathVariable for it. See below example:

```
@GetMapping(value="find/{id}")
public void find(@PathVariable Long id) {
    repository.findById(map.get("id"));
}
```

Also, Map should be considered for trivial payloads. If your payload has a complex structure with a number of nested JSON objects, you should use a DTO.

> I am currently using DTOs as BiDirectional. So, Using Bidirectional for DTOs is correct? Will am I going to face any issues with below DTOs design?

I don't see a problem with using bidirectional DTOs as these are just a means to transform your request/reponse data within the application. Had they been bidirectional entities, it would have been a problem w.r.t serialization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer. You actually didnt get my Query1.. My Query is related to POST..

Comment: Ohh okay..can you please explain it a bit more...I'll try to help accordingly.